# Can int value be assigned to id type + Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to know if this assignment is correct

```
id var = 9;
```

Will var be assigned the value 9 or do we have to wrap in some wrapper class like NSNumber?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible, but it is not correct:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

An `id` is a pointer to an object, not an integer.

- Do you intend to use the object available at address 9? You will unlikely be allowed to do that.
- Do you just want to use an `id` container to carry an integer? You should use `NSNumber` instead.
- Do you expect that the assignment will create an object containing 9? This doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 43):

9 is an integer literal, which is not an object. `id` is a pointer to an object. If you need to pass an integer as an object (type `id`) you have to wrap it inside a `NSNumber` object like this:

```
id var = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 9];
```

Answer (score 2):

`id var = @9;` works too. `@9` is equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]`